# When doing `char first_word[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = "test";`, is first_word a pointer or a string?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I have this code:

```
char first_word[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = "test";
printf("Word to input: %s\n", first_word);
printf("Word to input: %p\n", first_word);
```

It prints successfully for both (prints the string "test" and then an address).

In my code, I eventually do this:

```
char *arr_of_strings[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
arr_of_strings[0] = first_word;
```

and it properly sets `arr_of_strings[0]` to whatever `first_word` is (which in this case is a pointer because `*arr_of_strings` is an array of pointers, right?). But now when I do

```
printf("arr at 0 is: %s\n", arr_of_strings[0]);
```

It prints a string again, can I can also print an address like so:

```
printf("arr at 0 is: %p\n", arr_of_strings[0]);
```

So when does c use `first_word` as a string and when does it use it as a pointer?

Comment: It's strange that your code already answers your question. Every `first_word` is a pointer to the first character of the string. You're confusing the `first_word` in the `printf` line but `%s` already tells the compiler that associated variable holds the pointer to the first character of the string, not the string itself. So, it is the same for `arr_of_strings[0]`: when used with `%p`, it prints its pointer value; when used with `%s`, it prints the pointed string.

Comment: `first_word` is an array of `char`. that type is `char[MAX_LENGTH+1]`. When evaluated as an expression, pointer to first element(`&first_word[0]`). C-String  is a sequence of characters ending with a NUL character. Therefore, whether the pointer points is C-String depends on whether it is a sequence of characters to be terminated with NUL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is **an identifier for an array of characters.**

- It's **not a string**, because a *string* isn't even a type in C. A string in C is defined as a sequence of characters including one `0` / `'\0'` character at the end (indicating the end). So, `first_word` can **hold** a string, but you can't say it **is** a string. It can hold any sequence of `char`, not just strings.
- It's **not a pointer**, although it **evaluates to a pointer** in most contexts. Except when used with `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or `&`, the identifier of an array is evaluated as a pointer to it's first element. So, `first_word` will have the type `char *` (a pointer type) in many contexts, you could e.g. assign it to a pointer like `char *foo = first_word`. Still, **evaluating** to a pointer doesn't mean it **is** a pointer. The operators `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and `&` evaluate to very different results when used on an array vs. used on a pointer.

---

Regarding your question about printf: `%s` in printf requires a pointer to char (`char *`) to be passed and expects that pointer to point to a string. I hope you understand what that means after reading the explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in terms of exact variable lengths and addresses:

Case 1:

```
char str1[] = "test";
```

allocates a 5 bytes memory space, say from `0x0050` to `0x0054`, and `str1` is the address of the first character of the string; that is, `0x0050` in this case.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%s` format specifier, the compiler **knowing the `str1` is an array of characters**, directly sends the **address** of `str1` to the `printf` function and it prints the string.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%p` format specifier, the compiler **assumes that the coder is interested in the address of the string**; again sends the **address** of `str1` to the `printf` function and this time, it prints the address of the string.

Case 2:

```
char *str2 = "test";
```

allocates a 5 bytes memory space, say from `0x0050` to `0x0054`. This time however, `str2` is a pointer **stored in another address**, say `0x0030`; and it's value is `0x0050`, pointing the first character of the string.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%s` format specifier, the compiler **knowing the `str2` is a pointer to an array of characters**, sends the **value** stored in `str2` to the `printf` function; not the address of `str2`.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%p` format specifier, the compiler **assumes that the coder is interested in the address of the string**; again sends the **value** stored in `str2` to the `printf` function.

Case 3:

```
char *arrStr[4];
arrStr[0] = str1;
```

Here, the behavior of the compiler resembles the Case 2 above.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%s` format specifier, the compiler **knowing the `arrStr[0]` is a pointer to an array of characters**, sends the **value** stored in `arrStr[0]` to the `printf` function (and in fact, this is the address of `str1`); not the address of `arrStr[0]`.

When it is used in `printf` with a `%p` format specifier, the compiler **assumes that the coder is interested in the address of the string**; again sends the **value** stored in `arrStr[0]` to the `printf` function.

> So, if you're interested in the **address** of the `arrStr[0]` (not
>   the value that it is pointing to), you should use `&arrStr[0]` with a
>   `%p` format specifier.

Comment: `&arrStr[0]` is exactly the same as just `arrStr` without any operator, see my answer. (take these steps to see: `&arrStr[0]` -> `&(*(arrStr+0))` -> `&*arrStr`)